# how to customize useraccount dropdownlist in dnn6

Tags: dotnetnuke

In dnn6 Would you please go to admin->user accounts and look at the dropdown selector?  It shows you can search by username, email, etc but not by first name or last name.  Do you know how this dropdown gets poplulated so we can change it?

Comment: To change it you will likely need to make a core change, I haven't looked where it gets populated from. That being said, you should have FIRST MIDDLE and LAST as options for searching. Personally I would like to see DISPLAYNAME as a search option.

Comment: Thanks Chris...can you please tell me how i can add first name and  last name in dropdown....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why yours wouldn't be populating those fields, I didn't add them to mine, they were already there.

The Population of the dropdown occurs in the \desktopmodules\Admin\Security\Users.ascx.cs file

```
ProfilePropertyDefinitionCollection profileProperties = ProfileController.GetPropertyDefinitionsByPortal(PortalId, false, false);
```

So I would start by looking at your Profile Properties defined at the portal level, see if you have First/Last name there. You can find profile properties from the Admin/Site Settings page, on the Users Account Settings tab (under the profile settings section)

If you are using DNN6 (not DNN7) then you'll go to the Admin/User Accounts page and go to the actions for the user accounts module and find the User Profile Properties area.

Comment: Thanks Chris...yes i checked in profile property.....we have to check partcular field here....i dont know why first name and lastname not display..even they both are checked here....if you want then i can send you snapshot..?

Comment: If you run this SQL do you get first/last in the results? select * from ProfilePropertyDefinition where portalid=0 (you might need to change the ID to match a different portal if you aren't on PortalID 0

Comment: but why its not display in dropdown..?

Comment: Are they "visible" in the data that is returned from the SQL query? Is the datatype the same as the other fields that do work?

Comment: How about the "VISIBLE" column instead of default visibility?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll likely need to pull the DB down and run the site in debug mode to track this down further.

Comment: can you tell me the exact reason why its happening like this??